# CGAL Alpha Iterator Segmentation Fault (based on alpha shape 3D example)

Tags: c++, iterator, geometry, cgal, surface

I have the following code (found at bottom), and am trying to replicate the Alpha Shape 3D example found on the CGAL website (https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_3/index.html)

However, I get a segmentation fault, that comes from this line (found using gdb):

`std::cout << "Optimal alpha value to get one connected component is " << *opt << std::endl;`

The dataset used has been created by CGAL in OFF format from XYZ data. Its header looks like this:

```
./test.off

OFF
500 0 0
0.902989 -0.82769 -0.677893
0.822755 -0.402642 1.05875
1.33886 0.0517507 -0.405935
0.338283 0.0348648 -1.35807
0.0591201 -0.265762 -1.37327
0.188173 0.490894 1.29754
0.104928 0.512889 1.29844
0.639491 1.17839 -0.403047
-0.176474 0.134151 -1.38234
0.80777 0.0410059 -1.14273
-0.762083 0.370688 1.11437
0.903425 -1.06553 -0.0920476
-0.508653 -1.28935 0.197129
```

I believe that there must be a problem with the `Alpha_iterator` instance named `opt` since that is the only variable being pointed at in that line.

My question is what is causing the segmentation fault and how should I change my code so that this no longer happens?

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>

#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_cell_base_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_data_structure_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_utils_3.h>

#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Gt;

typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<Gt>         Vb;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_cell_base_3<Gt>           Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<Vb, Fb>  Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<Gt, Tds>     Triangulation_3;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_3<Triangulation_3>        Alpha_shape_3;

typedef Gt::Point_3                                 Point;
typedef Alpha_shape_3::Alpha_iterator               Alpha_iterator;

int main()
{
    std::list<Point> lp;

    // read input
    std::ifstream is("./test.off");
    int n;
    is >> n;
    std::cout << "Reading " << n << " points " << std::endl;
    Point p;
    for ( ; n>0 ; n--)
    {
        is >> p;
        lp.push_back(p);
    }

    // compute alpha shape
    Alpha_shape_3 as(lp.begin(), lp.end());
    std::cout << "Alpha shape computed in REGULARIZED mode by default" 
<< std::endl;

    // find optimal alpha value
    Alpha_iterator opt = as.find_optimal_alpha(1);
    std::cout << "Optimal alpha value to get one connected component 
is " << *opt << std::endl;
    as.set_alpha(*opt);
    assert(as.number_of_solid_components() == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check that the points were correctly read?

Comment: Also could you share in a gist the dataset?

Comment: @sloriot How can you check if the points are correctly read; I will edit the question to include more of the dataset but it is 3D Cartesian Co-ordinates with 500 points

Comment: this is not the way an OFF file should be read, trying with the 13 points provided shows that no point was read. Use [`read_off_points()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/group__PkgPointSetProcessingIO.html#ga1d0f58874ed1ddb2b00721f15ba362a9) or change the header of your file to have `500` followed by the points.